# How to propose a new meeting time on a recurring meeting series?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have accepted another persons recurring meeting invite, but then after a couple weeks realized there would be a better time to hold the meeting.

It looks like I can only propose a new time on an individual meeting day. Is there a way to propose a new time on the whole series? This question doesn't seem to be asked or answered by other questions on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Outlook 2016: We can propose new time for a SINGLE instance of the meeting alone. There is no option to propose a new time for the entire series.

So, I guess the simplest option is to mail the organiser to change the meeting series.

Official info here:

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/propose-a-new-meeting-time-in-outlook-c041b2c8-fc3c-43b1-979d-3b40463ac0a9

Specifically, the following part

```
Note: You can't propose a new time for a recurring meeting
```

- When the entire series is opened, the Ribbon bar does not show the 'Propose New Time'
- When an individual item is opened, the 'Propose New Time' option is shown

[image]

Comment: Thanks for linking to the source. I had been unable to find this. It's so inconspicuous on that page.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to the "Calendar" view
2. Select the meeting you want to prospose a new time for. (Single click, do not double-click and open the meeting)
3. Go to the "Meeting Series" tab in your ribbon toolbar
4. Click on the "Propose New Time" button in the "Respond" section.

Note: If you open the meeting request, you do not have the option.

Edit: Changed formatting.

Comment: This only refers to one single appointment, not the entire series in case of a recurring meeting. See the answer of Subbu: https://superuser.com/questions/1263029/how-to-propose-a-new-meeting-time-on-a-recurring-meeting-series/1334685#1334685

Answer (score 0):

Looks like MS does not allow. From https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/propose-a-new-meeting-time-in-outlook-c041b2c8-fc3c-43b1-979d-3b40463ac0a9

"Note: Meeting organizers can send meeting requests that restrict the ability to propose alternate meeting times. If the meeting organizer has restricted meeting proposals, the Propose New Time command isn’t available. Also, **you can’t propose a new time for recurring meetings.**"

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRp3v.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1184371)

Comment: 